# Network connections disappear right after Cisco VPN client installation

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I am trying to install and use Cisco VPN client on my machine. The VPN client version is 5.0.07.0440 64bit. My machine is Windows 7.

Right after installation completes both my network connections (WiFi and Ethernet) disappear and can not be restored. This situation continues after reboot. However, right after deinstallation (from Control Panel remove programs) the connections get restored and continue working like a charm. Again, this is not like other people report here, that they loose their other connection after they open a connection with VPN client. My problem appears immediately after the VPN client completes its installation.

The VPN Client itself can not establish any connection either, as it relies on network interfaces it just caused to go down.

Additional thing I could notice is that there is an additional Deterministic Network Enhancer Miniport device installed per each network interface, but they appear as not fully functional (the yellow warning mark is displayed along their icons).

I have VirtualBox installed on this machine, does that matter?

What could be wrong here and how can I get the VPN client installed and running smoothly?

Comment: I have a similar problem: Windows XP VM running in Windows 7 x64 using Windows Virtual PC.  Install Cisco VPN Client and immediately lose my 2 network connections.  XP thinks that those connections are still connected, but nothing network related works, for example, ipconfig doesn't show anything listed at all (no adapters, no ip info, just blank).

I don't have that Deterministic Network Enhancer Miniport though.

Did you ever get this resolved?  Does anyone out there know what's happening here?